# Callback function in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, callback

I have to call a api (SOAP) with a callback (asynchron), result..etc.
The methods I have to use:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginInsertIncident(
    string userName, string password, string MsgId, string ThirdPartyRef,
    string Type, string EmployeeId, string ShortDescription, string Details,
    string Category, string Service, string OwnerGrp, string OwnerRep,
    string SecondLevelGrp, string SecondLevelRep, string ThirdLevelGrp,
    string ThirdLevelRep, string Impact, string Urgency, string Priority,
    string Source, string Status, string State, string Solution,
    string ResolvedDate, string Cause, string Approved, AsyncCallback callback,
    object asyncState);

EndInsertIncident(IAsyncResult asyncResult, out string msg);
```

EndInsertIncident close the request in the Ticketsystem and give a result if the ticket is correctly done.

Status Quo:

```
server3.ILTISAPI api = new servert3.ILTISAPI();
api.BeginInsertIncident(username, "", msg_id, "", "", windows_user,
    "BISS - Software Deployment", "", "", "NOT DETERMINED", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "5 - BAU", "3 - BAU", "", "Interface", "", "", "", "", "", "", null,
    null);
```

So, now, how I implement the Callback-Function?
The Status of the api "InsertIncidentCompleted" ist already null, cause I don't call the EndInsertIncident, I think.

I'm new in C# and need some help.

Comment: Side note: **Worst function signature ever.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AsyncCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx) is a delegate that returns void and takes one parameter of type `IAsyncResult`.

So, create a method with this signature and pass it as the second to last parameter:

```
private void InsertIncidentCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // do something and then:
    string message;
    api.EndInsertIncident(result, out message);
}
```

Pass it like this:

```
api.BeginInsertIncident(username, "", msg_id, "", "", windows_user,
    "BISS - Software Deployment", "", "", "NOT DETERMINED", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "5 - BAU", "3 - BAU", "", "Interface", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    InsertIncidentCallback, null);
```

If you can't make `api` a member variable of your class and want to pass it to your callback, you would have to do something like this:

```
private void InsertIncidentCallback(server3.ILTISAPI api, IAsyncResult result)
{
    // do something and then:
    string message;
    api.EndInsertIncident(result, out message);
}
```

To be able to pass this as a callback, you will have to use a delegate:

```
api.BeginInsertIncident(..., r => InsertIncidentCallback(api, r), null);
```

Comment: @ManuelFischer: You need to make `api` a member variable of the class containing your methods.

Comment: could I call the methode InsertIncidentCallback with the api variable, like ....InsertIncidentCallback(api),null); ?

Comment: ok, now I have a errorcode "CS1525" > invalid expression. I dont know the operator =>?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? `=>` is the lambda operator.

Comment: Im working with vs 2005, .Net 3.5

Comment: Wow, VS2005? That's really old. Try using this instead: `delegate(IAsyncResult r) { InsertIncidentCallback(api, r) }`

Comment: Ya, I know...Its easier to define a global variable?  CS1002: ; anticipated. After the delegate(IAsyncResult r) { InsertIncidentCallback(api, r) }

Comment: @ManuelFischer: Yeah, sorry. Put that missing semicolon after the call to `InsertIncidentCallback`: `delegate(IAsyncResult r) { InsertIncidentCallback(api, r); }`

Comment: ok, know it works. I debugged through the code but the `InsertIncidentCallback` never called.

Comment: @ManuelFischer: It will be called after some time by the code that is started inside `api.BeginInsertIncident`. If that doesn't happen, I can't help anymore, because that's an issue with the API. However, don't expect it to be called when you step over the line with `api.BeginInsertIncident`. To check if it is called, put a break-point into `InsertIncidentCallback` and run your program.

Comment: ok. I get a Error. Sounds if I dont filled the required informations.
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: ERROR (48272): ; Required information is missing/invalid.  Please be sure to specify valid values for the following fields:  First Name, Last Name, Service Type, Status, Impact, Urgency, Description and Reported Source.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message,.....

Comment: @ManuelFischer: Good. Fill them in. But this is no longer in the scope of this quesion. If you need to, please ask a new one.